# How to disable Vscode extension "better comments" when writing out a string

Tags: visual-studio-code

The moment I type a / I get all of the options for creating comments right on top of the auto-completed paths I wish to use, how do I change this so it doesn't show when I am writing out a string (anything inside a set of " ")

`const typeDefs = require("./typeDefs");`

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpLWQ.png)